# Positioning items to maximize separation subject to constraints

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming, np-complete, operations-research

Say we want to place n items on the real line. Let us denote the position of item i by $p_i$. We have interval constraints on the position $p_i$, i.e. we are given $l_i, r_i$ such that $l_i \le p_i \le r_i$. My problem is: given a specific item s, what is the maximum gap possible to the right of s? By maximum gap to the right of s I mean the distance between s and the next item to its right.

#### Mathematical Description:

More formally, I want to find
 $$f(s) = \max_{p_1,\dots,p_n} p_t - p_s$$ subject to 
\begin{align*}
1)\,& l_i \le p_i \le r_i\, \forall\,i \in [n] \\
2)\,& \forall\,i\ne s,t: p_i \le p_s \text{ or }p_i \ge p_t \text{ (there is no item between s and t)}
\end{align*}

In the absence of the second constraint the problem would have been a linear program. The second constraint makes it difficult.

Is this a known problem? Is it hard? Is there a dynamic programming solution? I am stuck because I don't know how to formulate the ordering of the items.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is second condition such a problem? You just sort $p_i$ by their value and only compare neighbors

Comment: Your second constraint presumes that both $s$ and $t$ are specified (with item $t$ to immediately follow item $s$). Is that intentional? If you want to allow any item with appropriate bounds to follow $s$, you'll need binary variables to determine which index $t$ comes immediately after $s$.

Comment: I only assume that s is known. I do not assume knowledge of $t,p_s,p_t$. The fact that t should immediately follow s is encoded in the second constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model the second constraint with binary variables :
$$
p_i \le p_s + M(1-y_{is})\\
p_i \ge p_t - My_{is}\\
y_{is} \in \{0,1\}
$$

Comment: Thanks. That will have a complexity of $O(2^n)$ linear programs. I was wondering if an easier solution is possible.

Comment: Mixed integer linear programs are virtually never solved by trying all combinations of the integer variables and solving every possible LP. So your actual computational time will likely be much better than that.

Comment: I agree. But I am interested in an actual algorithm, not in modeling this as an IP and using a solver.